# Invalid conversion while allocating memory with alloca

Tags: c++, arduino

This code

```
#include "alloca.h"

String str = "abc";

unsigned int *i;

void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(9600);

  i = alloca(StringLength() * sizeof(i));

  unsigned int j[StringLength() * sizeof(i)];
}

int StringLength() {
  return str.length();
}

void loop() {
}
```

gives me the following error messages:

> sketch_dec11f.cpp: In function ‘void setup()’:
>   sketch_dec11f.cpp:14:7: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘unsigned int*’

What am I doing wrong?

(tried it with malloc() as well, also didn't work!)

Comment: So you are actually using C++, not C?

Comment: in fact it's arduino... but yes, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely don't want `alloca()`.  That's an allocation that is on the stack of the function and only lasts for the duration of the call.  It lets you have dynamic arrays that go away on function return (in C++ you could do this with RAII, but in C `alloca` was the only way).

You just need a cast in your allocation.  Try `i = (unsigned int *)malloc(StringLength() * sizeof(*i))`.  Note the `sizeof(*i)`.  That's the size of one member:  `sizeof(i)` is the size of the pointer and is not likely to be related to what's inside.

Comment: Even better, don't use `malloc` if you're writing C++.

Answer (score 1):

Malloc and alloca return void * pointers. Just change

```
i = alloca(StringLength() * sizeof(i));
```

to

```
i = (unsigned int *)alloca(StringLength() * sizeof(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of alloca, but malloc return's void * and C++ unlike C doesn't support implicit conversion from void * to any other pointer type. This is one of the many areas where C++ differs from C.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the returning pointer from alloca:

```
i = (unsigned int *) alloca(StringLength() * sizeof(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++, void pointers are *not* implicitly convertible to other pointers, unlike in C. Therefore you need a cast:

```
i = static_cast<unsigned int *>(alloca(StringLength() * sizeof(i)));
```